# Random movement algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, random

I'm basically trying to write down a very basic algorithm that lets a char "move" into a preset map of chars.

What I need to do, is to get the char moving to a next position which must be empty (checked with == ' ' over the map matrix values); if there are both horizontal or vertical need to chose one randomly.

What I've done so far is VERY messy: 
I first check if there's an empty tile next to the char, if there is one, check if vertically both next tiles are free, if free chose one randomly, then do the same for X axis.
If neither vertical\horizontal axis has both free next tiles, find one free and set it as the direction taken.

Now, I don't know if the logic is actually correct but I couldn't come to a better AND working solution. Open to any suggestion.

```
if(map[charPos.y-2][charPos.x-1] == ' ' || map[charPos.y][charPos.x-1] == ' '
|| map[charPos.y-1][charPos.x-2] == ' ' || map[charPos.y-1][charPos.x] == ' '){

    if ((map[charPos.y-2][charPos.x-1] == ' ' && map[charPos.y][charPos.x-1] == ' ')
        || (map[charPos.y-1][charPos.x-2] == ' ' && map[charPos.y-1][charPos.x] == ' ')){
        if ( map[charPos.y-2][charPos.x-1] == ' ' && map[charPos.y][charPos.x-1] == ' '){
        chosenDir = rand() % (DIR_DW - DIR_UP + 1) + DIR_UP;
        } else if (map[charPos.y-1][charPos.x-2] == ' ' && map[charPos.y-1][charPos.x] == ' '){
        chosenDir = rand() % (DIR_RT - DIR_LT + 1) + DIR_LT;
        }
    } else if(map[charPos.y-2][charPos.x-1] == ' '){
                chosenDir=DIR_UP;
    } else if(map[charPos.y][charPos.x-1] == ' '){
                chosenDir=DIR_DW;
    } else if(map[charPos.y-1][charPos.x-2] == ' '){
                chosenDir=DIR_LT;
    } else if(map[charPos.y-1][charPos.x] == ' '){
                chosenDir=DIR_RT;
    }
}

switch (chosenDir){
    case DIR_UP: {
        charPos.y-=1;
    }
    case DIR_DW: {
        charPos.y+=1;
    }
    case DIR_LT: {
        charPos.x-=1;
    }
    case DIR_RT: {
        charPos.x+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now, first properly indent your code so it is readable.

Comment: Would you do better establishing a list (array) of possible moves, and then selecting one of those moves at random?  Without declarations, it's hard to know types, but maybe `int poss_dir[4]; int num_poss = 0; if (map[charPos.y-2][charPos.x-1] == ' ') poss_dir[num_poss++] = DIR_UP; …3 more…; int chosen = rand() % num_poss; …`?

Comment: Note that you need `break;` statements in your `switch` — you have `switch (chosenDir){
    case DIR_UP: {
        charPos.y-=1;
    }
    case DIR_DW: {
        charPos.y+=1;
    }
    case DIR_LT: {
        charPos.x-=1;
    }
    case DIR_RT: {
        charPos.x+=1;
    }
}` and if `chosenDir` is `DIR_UP`, all four operations will be performed.  The internal braces are unnecessary and potentially misleading.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I actually already thought about the solution you're telling me, but there's one problem: how do you correctly choose a random possible next tile? let's say I checked all 4  possible tiles to move with `if (tile == ' ') isLegal[dir] = true` and only DOWN and RIGHT are free, with those being constants defined like enums (DIR_UP = 0, DIR_DW = 1 etc...), how would you choose one of them randomly being 1 and 3, excluding the 2 (DIR_LT)?

Comment: Also consider whether you should create an array of a structure type that gives the `delta_x` and `delta_y` values for each direction: `struct Move { int delta_x; int delta_y; } moves[] = { [DIR_UP] = { 0, -1 }, [DIR_DW] = { 0, +1 }, [DIR_LT = { -1, 0 }, [DIR_RT] = { +1, 0 } };` then you can use `charPos.x += moves[chosenDir].delta_x; charPos.y += moves[chosenDir].delta_y;` and avoid using the `switch` statement.  Basically, I'm suggesting you use more data structures to simplify the code.

Comment: I showed how to select a direction at random with `int chosen = rand() % num_poss;` . The value in `chosen` is (more or less) a random value from the set of available moves.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler gonna try to update my code with your suggestions and check if it's working properly!

Comment: The value in `chosen` is "(more or less) a random value from the set of available moves".  You can refine the algorithm to choose a number from the range 0..3 (or 0..2 or 0..1, or 0..0) to avoid bias — use a function to generate the number: `int random(int range) { int value; int max = RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX % range; while ((value = rand()) > max) ; return value % range; }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler using that solution is not working since num_poss will increment infinitely till there's a free tile which you can move into.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203344/discussion-between-thz-and-jonathan-leffler).